# How do I load a nib file through storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to load a particular scene from storyboard dynamically using it's story board id. It is more like loading a separate nib file through storyboard. I have a scene with a storyboard id "storyid". Then I'm trying to load it but unable get that scene on my screen when it is loaded. I get no errors in the code.

```
- (IBAction)btnLoadSceneClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"btnLoadSceneClicked");
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyid"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
YourViewControllerClass * viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyid"];
[self presentViewController: animated:YES completion:^{ /* what happens when the viewController is presented */}]
```

You could also push the viewController if you are embedded in a navigation controller.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)btnLoadSceneClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"btnLoadSceneClicked");
     YourViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyBoardID"];
    [viewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50f animations:^{
        [viewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}
```